# OpenGL Display List Optimizing

Tags: c++, opengl, optimization

I am currently running some speed tests for my applications and I am trying to find more ways to optimize my program, specifically with my display lists. Currently I am getting:

12 FPS with 882,000 vertices

40 FPS with 234,000 vertices

95 FPS with 72,000 vertices

I know that I need to minimize the number of calls made, so instead of:

```
for(int i = 0; i < Number; i++) {
   glBegin(GL_QUADS);
   ...normal and vertex declarations here
   glEnd();
}
```

A better way would be to do this:

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
for(int i = 0; i < Number; i++) {
   ...normal and vertex declarations here
}
glEnd();
```

This did help increase my FPS to the results listed above, however, are there other ways I can optimize my display lists? Perhaps by using something other than nested vertex arrays to store my model data?

Comment: What do you mean by "nested vertex arrays"?

Comment: By that I meant an std::vector of a std::vector. I basically have a struct that contains std::vectors of other structs, which in turn contain std::vectors

Comment: OpenGL doesn't have any interfaces that take a `std::vector`, so again what are you talking about?

Comment: I use std::vector to store my variables I need for opengl calls, such as vertex and normal data. I then call it like:

    glVertex3f(Model[i].XVert, Model[i].YVert, Model[i].ZVert);

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll get a significant speed boost by switching to [VBOs](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vbo.html) or at least [Vertex arrays](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vertexarray.html).

Immediate mode (`glBegin()...glEnd()`) has a lot of method call overhead. I've managed to render ~1 million vertices at several hundred fps on a laptop (would be faster without the physics engine/entity system overhead too) by using more modern OpenGL.

If you're wondering about compatibility, about 98% of people support the VBO extension (`GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object`) http://feedback.wildfiregames.com/report/opengl/

Comment: So is the OpenGL Vertex Array faster than a std::vector? And for VBOs, is there a maximum number of vertices they can handle with the FPS still being reasonable (60 FPS or above)?

Comment: Yes, the vertex array is faster than the std::vector. Unless you're using really old hardware, your vertices will be stored in the graphics card memory rather than your main memory. There will be a major speedup, because you won't be having to send all the vertices back to the graphics card in every frame.

Comment: OpenGL is a client server API so the more data that can be uploaded to the server the better. The GPU (server) has its own memory and can be though of as another computer. VBOs are uploaded once and can be easily accessible but the GPU

Comment: vertex arrays are faster because you use a single method call to send over all your vertices instead of multiple methods per vertex. And AFAIK the limit for VBOs is as much VRAM you have on your graphics card. If you're not doing anything more than some simple shading, you can have a few million vertices rendering at well over 60 fps.